# xades4j: Sign only one element

Tags: java, xml, xades4j

I'm using this code to sign a xml document:

```
Document doc = getDocument(xml_to_sign);
Element elemToSign = doc.getDocumentElement();

String file_uri_path = elemToSign.getBaseURI();

DataObjectDesc obj1 = new DataObjectReference(file_uri_path).withType("http://www.gzs.si/shemas/eslog/racun/1.5#Racun");
SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects(obj1);

signer.sign(dataObjs, elemToSign);
```

xml_to_sign is the full path to the xml file.

The problem is, that I would like to sign only the node with the id "data" (#data), but append the signature to the node elemToSign.

Is it possible to do this with xades4j?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. The [sign method](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.1/javadoc/reference/xades4j/production/XadesSigner.html)'s argument is the **parent node**, not the element to sign (it could be the same node, depending on the configured references). In your example you should add a reference for "#data":

```
Document doc = getDocument(xml_to_sign);
Element parent = doc.getDocumentElement();

DataObjectDesc obj1 = new DataObjectReference("#data").withType("http://www.gzs.si/shemas/eslog/racun/1.5#Racun");
SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects(obj1);

signer.sign(dataObjs, parent);
```

Another option is to add a reference for the whole XML document (empty URI) and use a XPath transform.

Comment: I've tried doing that, but I get an exception: "Cannot resolve element with ID data", but I have the element <Racun Id="data">

Comment: Probably that element's Id attribute needs to be set as its "XML Id" in order to have "getElementById" work (used internally by Apache's resolver).

Answer (score 0):

You should specify that the attribute named "Id" in your xml document is the XML ID attribute that Apache Santuario (used internally by Xades4j) will use in the getElementById() (as lgoncalves has pointed out in his commments to his own answer).

```
Element parent = doc.getDocumentElement();
parent.setIdAttribute("Id", true);
//or parent.setIdAttributeNS("http://your.name.space", "Id", true);
```

I had the same problem, and this additional line of code solved it.